# If a harmonic function is constant in two points then it is constant in infinitely many points

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

If $u$ is a harmonic function defined on an open set onto $\mathbb{R}$, and we know that there exists $x_0,y_0$ such that $u(x_0)+u(y_0)=M$ for some constant $M$, show that there exist infinitely many points $(x,y)$ such that $u(x)+u(y)=M$.

First I tried to use the mean-value property but as $M$ is not the maximum I cannot conclude anything by using inequalities as to prove the mean-value property itself. I also tried to prove that the set $A=\{(x,y) : u(x)+u(y)=M\}$ is open and closed and as it is nonempty (since $(x_0,y_0) \in A$) it should  be the whole set where $u$ is defined (since it is a domain, so it is connected), BUT, I don`t know how to prove it is open, since I would need the mean-value property. If anybody could help me to solve this exercise...Thank you

Comment: Hello. Welcome to MathStack Exchange. I cannot help with your question, but I fixed the math writing using MathJax. Take a look to see how it goes.

Comment: thanks, I don't know how to use it yet.

Comment: There is a lot of LaTeX material on the web, it is worth tô learn as soon as possible

Comment: points $(x,y)$ such that $u(x)+u(y)=M?$ Weird notation.

Comment: the set of points in the domain of u such that u(x)+u(y)=M

Comment: "If $u$ is a harmonic function defined on an open set onto $\mathbb{R}$" what does that mean? You need to tell us more about the setting. Where are we, $\mathbb R^2?$ $\mathbb R^n?$

Comment: You are right, Open set of Rn, call it U c Rn. i.e. u: U--->R where U is connected

Comment: $A$ need not be open. It's open if and only if $u$ is constant. Consider $v \colon U \times U \to \mathbb{R},\; v(x,y) = u(x) + u(y)$ and use the mean value property.

Comment: Do I have to equal the double integral of the mean-value prop.) of v to the sum of two integrals of u (one of each in the ball centered at x_0, y_0 resp.)?

Comment: If I derivate the integral, I get that the integral in the boundary of the ball of v(x,y) is zero. But I don't know how can I conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For all small $r>0,$ there must exist a point $x_r\in \{x: |x-x_0| = r\}$ such that $u(x_r) = u(x_0).$ Otherwise the MVP does not hold at $x_0.$ Same thing at $y_0.$

Comment: I don't know how to use this hint.

Comment: @IreneGil For each $r, u(x_0)$ is the average of $u$ over the sphere I mentioned. $u$ is continuous and the sphere is connected. Thus $u$ must take on the value $u(x_0)$ on this sphere.

Comment: firstly, thank you for answering me. But then why the problem is telling me u(x_0)+u(y_0)=M and not only u(x_0)? and, how can I prove it by using the mean value property?

Comment: can I do it by setting v(x,y) and the same argument you used before but with the ball centered in (x_0,y_0) and radius r? and using the mean value propoerty in R2n for v(x,y)?

Comment: You are making this too difficult. Note my sentence "Same thing at $y_0$"

Comment: ok, sorry.I just wanted to ensure that I was doing it well.